# Which is best way to hold raw data temporary?

Tags: php, mysql, view, web, analytics

I am working on some analytic web application. Every time i need **processed raw data** from database to be hold temporary. 
So, what will be best way to hold that raw data temporary.

1) Temporary Table
2) Cache
3) Hash map
4) View
5) Actual table
6) Temporary file
7) ....

there will heavy read & write operations.

Please suggest.

Comment: The GLARING ommission from your question is whether the data will be accessed by more than one thread of execution - which then begs the question of what OS this running on and whether it is practical to implement custom daemons. Also, whether the data will need to be accessible by multiple nodes in a cluster - how scalable must the solution be...any responses you get will random guesses based on the respondent's experience - not a solution to your problem.

Comment: Revoked bounty and closed as unclear - we need a LOT more information about what you're doing to answer this effectively.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what exactly you are tracking, and how much data you have. In the simplest terms, tables housing temporary information in your existing database could do it. On the opposite end of the spectrum, you could have MongoDB housing aggregate data with Memcached/Varnish caching entire HTTP responses with TTLs.

Cheers

Comment: I am looking for mysql only.

Comment: If you are looking to keep everything in mysql, then map your raw data table to an abstraction table. Run your calculations, and insert them into the abstraction table. Then, your app can just query against this table.

Comment: I think your saying about **view**?

Comment: No. If you are actually processing the data, you will need to create a table for the data once it has been processed.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using Redis or APC. These are key-value storages which will perfectly fit for your purpose of storing processed data and sharing it between sessions/requests.

Wish you luck!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use PHP Session Variables.  It holds the data, and is easily referenced when needed.

Comment: I have large amount of data to process so session is not good way to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a table in database to hold data and delete content afterwards

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to go for database table because it will be persist until you remove it.

session may not be good option because it will be lost if the user closes browser and also you can not store large amount of data into session.

Answer (score 0):

A temp file is never a good choice because it's always vulnerable. A table in the database is the best way to store temporary data since you can even set a time for it to get truncated if you're sure about how much time you need that information to be there!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a caching solution.
My personal experience with APC for similar use cases has been good.

Using APC, I have been able to avoid the additional overhead of hitting the db every time I need to access the data. Its useful because I need to access the data multiple times in a short span of time and then discard it. So using a db solution did not seem to be as efficient.
Further more, its easier to access APC, as data read/write is as simple as key => value, I guess a file read/write solution might require a bit more complex code.

The few things you need to be careful of are, the data could be lost in the instance of a server restart.